# Unable to conditionally render component children: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to conditionally render some components in React, but am continually faced with the below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

The `getChannels` async function is what is causing the error to fire. I believe it is returning undefined when it initially renders and so therefore causes the error to fire. I have be looking for another way to render the components out, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Here is the full code for this component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import LanguageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Language';
import ChannelOption from './ChannelOption';
import { firestore } from '../firebase';

const Sidebar = () => {
    
    const getChannels = async () => {
        const snapshot = await firestore.collection('rooms').get()
        console.log(snapshot.docs[0].data());
        const rooms = await snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.data().name);
            return <ChannelOption title={doc.data().name}></ChannelOption>
        })
        return rooms;   
    }

    return (
        <SidebarContainer>
            {/* Search */}
            <SidebarSearchContainer>
                <SidebarSearch placeholder="Find or create a channel"/>
            </SidebarSearchContainer>
            {/* Channels */}
            <ChannelContainer>
                <ChannelHeader>
                    <ChannelHeaderText>Channels</ChannelHeaderText>
                    <AddIconStyled style={{ fontSize: 16 }}/>
                </ChannelHeader>
                {getChannels()?.docs.map((doc) => {
                    return <ChannelOption 
                        key={doc.id} 
                        id={doc.id} 
                        title={doc.data().name} 
                    />
                })}
            </ChannelContainer>
            {/* Profile */}
            <ProfileContainer>

            </ProfileContainer>
        </SidebarContainer>
    )
}

export default Sidebar;

const SidebarContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 30rem;
    background-color: var(--dark-blue-2);
`;

const SidebarSearchContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5.5rem;
    border-bottom: 0.1rem solid var(--dark-blue-4);
`;

const SidebarSearch = styled.input`
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    height: 3rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .4rem;
    background-color: var(--dark-blue-4);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
`;

const ChannelContainer = styled.div`
    width: 90%;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 1.25rem;
`;

const ChannelHeader = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
`;

const ChannelBlock = styled.div`
`;

const ChannelHeaderText = styled.div`
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: var(--light-grey-1);
`;

const AddIconStyled = styled(AddIcon)`
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    color: var(--light-grey-1);
`;

const ProfileContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    margin-top: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5.5rem;
    background-color: var(--dark-blue-5);
`;
```

Would be super appreciative of any suggestions - thank you for reading!

Comment: You should avoid using `Promises` in the return statement of the component. In your case `getChannels` is a method that returns a Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `docs` exists before you try to map over it. You also can't make a function that renders JSX asynchronous (i.e. using `await`).

Try this. I've added a couple of comments to explain:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import LanguageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Language';
import ChannelOption from './ChannelOption';
import {firestore} from '../firebase';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [snapshot, setSnapShot] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    initSnapShot();
  }, []);

  const initSnapShot = async () => {
    const snap = await firestore.collection('rooms').get();
    console.log(snap.docs[0].data());
    setSnapShot(snap);
  };

  const renderChannels = () => // functions that render JSX MUST NOT be async. The async logic already happens in `initSnapShot`.
    snapshot.docs.map(doc => { // just return this directly. The variable doesn't add anything.
      console.log(doc.data().name);
      return <ChannelOption title={doc.data().name} key={doc.id} id={doc.id}></ChannelOption>;
    });

  return (
    <SidebarContainer>
      {/* Search */}
      <SidebarSearchContainer>
        <SidebarSearch placeholder='Find or create a channel' />
      </SidebarSearchContainer>
      {/* Channels */}
      <ChannelContainer>
        <ChannelHeader>
          <ChannelHeaderText>Channels</ChannelHeaderText>
          <AddIconStyled style={{fontSize: 16}} />
        </ChannelHeader>
        {/* Make sure `docs` exists so you don't map over `undefined` */}
        {snapshot && snapshot.docs && renderChannels()} 
      </ChannelContainer>
      {/* Profile */}
      <ProfileContainer></ProfileContainer>
    </SidebarContainer>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional commentary regarding the render function not being async, that makes a lot of sense - can see that this is rendering perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first fetch the data and set it to state before rendering any content;

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import LanguageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Language';
import ChannelOption from './ChannelOption';
import { firestore } from '../firebase';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [snapshot, setSnapShot] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    initSnapShot()
  }, [])

  const initSnapShot = async () => {
    const snap = await firestore.collection('rooms').get()
    console.log(snap.docs[0].data());
    setSnapShot(snap);
  }

  const renderChannels = () => {
    const rooms = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data().name);
      return <ChannelOption title={doc.data().name}
        key={doc.id}
        id={doc.id}
      ></ChannelOption>
    })
    return rooms;
  }

  return (
    <SidebarContainer>
      {/* Search */}
      <SidebarSearchContainer>
        <SidebarSearch placeholder="Find or create a channel" />
      </SidebarSearchContainer>
      {/* Channels */}
      <ChannelContainer>
        <ChannelHeader>
          <ChannelHeaderText>Channels</ChannelHeaderText>
          <AddIconStyled style={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
        </ChannelHeader>
        {snapshot && renderChannels()}
      </ChannelContainer>
      {/* Profile */}
      <ProfileContainer>

      </ProfileContainer>
    </SidebarContainer>
  )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: @James i edited the ans. The ``async`` keyword was from the code in the question. I forgot to remove it